# How to set default language programmatically in OpenCart 3?

Tags: php, cross-browser, opencart-3

I'm trying to set the default language programmatically in OpenCart 3 when user for the first time visit the website.
I tried a lot but I have 2 problems which I can't find a solution for them:

1. I don't know how to set the default language programmatically
2. How to detect if the website / page loads for the first time

Here is the code I tried:

```
$supportedLangs = array('en', 'ru', 'ar', 'fa', 'tr');

$languages = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

foreach($languages as $lang)
{
    $lan = explode(';',$lang);
    if (strlen($lan[0]) <= 2) {
        if(in_array($lan[0], $supportedLangs))
        {
            $this->language->set($lan[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `cookies` to check if the website has ever loaded on that client/browser. Set a cookie with some info like default language after the website is loaded first time. And put a check also on header file for that `cookie`, if it exists that's a `returning user` for you. If it doesn't exist most probably that's a `new user`.